# VBA UDF evaluates after every change

Tags: excel, vba, user-defined-functions

I have an issue, I thought would be a pretty simple one, but now can't handle it so I guess was wrong.
I have a UDF that calculates the average of exchange rates between 2 dates

```
Option Explicit
Public Function averageFromRange() As Double

Dim sh As Worksheet
Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Exchange Rates")

Dim dateStart As Date: dateStart = sh.range("G1").Value
Dim dateEnd As Date: dateEnd = sh.range("G2").Value

Dim myRange As String
Dim rangeStart As range
Dim rangeEnd As range

Set rangeStart = sh.range("A:A").Find(What:=CStr(dateStart), LookAt:=xlWhole, LookIn:=xlValues).Offset(0, 1)
Set rangeEnd = sh.range("A:A").Find(What:=CStr(dateEnd), LookAt:=xlWhole, LookIn:=xlValues).Offset(0, 1)

If rangeStart Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox ("Date " & dateStart & " out of range")
End If

If rangeEnd Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox ("Date " & dateEnd & " out of range")
End If

If Not (rangeStart Is Nothing Or rangeEnd Is Nothing) Then
    myRange = rangeStart.Address & ":" & rangeEnd.Address
    averageFromRange = Application.WorksheetFunction.Average(range(myRange))
End If
End Function
```

Any change in the entire workbook (apart from the sheet in which the function is called) re-evaluates the function to #VALUE!. I tried both parametrizing the UDF to have these dates as input params, and activating the sheet. I have no other ideas how to handle this issue. Could you help me out?

Comment: `range(myRange))` - this is implicitly working against the `ActiveSheet`. Try `sh.Range(myRange)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Function returns `#VALUE!` when any of the `dateStart` or `dateEnd` is not found in column `[A:A]` because of these lines:

```
Set rangeStart = sh.range("A:A").Find(What:=CStr(dateStart), LookAt:=xlWhole, LookIn:=xlValues).Offset(0, 1)
Set rangeEnd = sh.range("A:A").Find(What:=CStr(dateEnd), LookAt:=xlWhole, LookIn:=xlValues).Offset(0, 1)
```

Those lines are trying to set the `Offset(0, 1)` of `Nothing` *(i.e. `Find` returns `Nothing` and the lines are still trying to return the `Offset`)*

*Solution:* First find the `Cell` containing the `Dates` then if the dates are found, set the `Offset` range.

Also you may want the UDF be [Volatile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.volatile) if Column `[A:A]` or the `Dates` (start & end) are updated by formulas.

Try this code:

```
Public Function averageFromRange() As Double

Dim dDateIni As Date, dDateEnd As Date
Dim rINI As Range, rEND As Range

    Application.Volatile    'Comment this line is VOLATILE is not required
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Exchange Rates")
    
        dDateIni = .Range("G1").Value
        dDateEnd = .Range("G2").Value
    
        With .Columns(1)
            Set rINI = .Find(What:=CStr(dDateIni), LookAt:=xlWhole, LookIn:=xlValues)
            Set rEND = .Find(What:=CStr(dDateEnd), LookAt:=xlWhole, LookIn:=xlValues)
        End With
    
    End With
            
    If rINI Is Nothing Then MsgBox ("Date " & dDateIni & " out of range")
    If rEND Is Nothing Then MsgBox ("Date " & dDateEnd & " out of range")
    If Not (rINI Is Nothing And rEND Is Nothing) Then
        averageFromRange = Application.Average(Range(rINI.Offset(0, 1), rEND.Offset(0, 1)))
    End If
        
    End Function
```

Resources used:
[Worksheet.Range](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.range),
[With statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/with-statement)

Comment: Hmm, I passed that code, works fine until I run any other sub. And when I do, I get 2 MsgBoxes, so dates out of range which is weird, because they are in range and in order to fix it again, i need to re-call the function. I removed volatile instruction, but didnt change much.

Comment: Your original problem is solved, the UDF does not returns #VALUE! anymore, which is the scope of this question. Your new problem does not seems to be related to the `UDF`, but to how the dates are updated, debug the function and find out what the actual values are when it generates the messages. Suggest to add `Application.Calculation=xlCalculationManual` at the beginning of the other subs and 
`Application.Calculation=xlCalculationAutomatic` at the end so the `UDF` is not trigger till the other subs have ended.